# Regex conditioning

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following:

```
a;b{c;d;}e{f;}
```

How can I split this into three groups like so:

```
Group 1: a;
Group 2: b{c;d;}
Group 3: e{f;}
```

I'm learning regular expressions and I was wondering if I could include a if-then-else type logic into the expression.

What I have now:

```
(.*?{.*?})
```

This creates two groups like so:

```
Group 1: a;b{c;d;}
Group 2: e{f;}
```

which is not what I want as a; and b{c;d;} are merged.

Pseudo if-then-else:

1. Select all characters until either a semi-colon or open curly
   bracket.
2. If semi-colon then stop and complete group.
3. Else if open curly bracket then continue selecting all characters
   until closing curly bracket.

Thanks.

Comment: The simplest expression you can use is [`re.findall(r"[^;{]+;|[^}]+\}", text)`](http://ideone.com/7tfoSC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall`

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^;{]+;?(?:{[^}]*})?', 'a;b{c;d;}e{f;}')
['a;', 'b{c;d;}', 'e{f;}']
```

OR

This one is the more appropriate one.

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^;{]+;|[^;{]+(?:{[^}]*})?', 'a;b{c;d;}e{f;}')
['a;', 'b{c;d;}', 'e{f;}']
```

- `[^;{]+` negated character class which matches any char but not of `;` or `{` one or more times.
- `|` OR
- `[^;{]+`  any char but not of ; or `{` followed by an
- `(?:{[^}]*})?` optional curly brace block.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=;)(?![^{]*})|(?<=}(?!$))
```

You can use this to split with `regex` module as `re` does not support split at `0 width assertions`.

```
import regex
x="a;b{c;d;}e{f;}"
print regex.split(r"(?<=;)(?![^{]*})|(?<=}(?!$))",x,flags=regex.VERSION1)
```

Output:`['a;', 'b{c;d;}', 'e{f;}']`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/8#python